# Change Image of Array onPress React Native

Tags: arrays, image, react-native, closures

I am having trouble figuring out how to change image on press using React Native. I basically have an array of images, which I want to display/change one by one, as the user presses on the image. 
Here is my code so far:

```
var MOOD_LIST =  ["sunny", "cloudy", "thunderstorm", "warm", "suncloudy"];

var MOODS = {
  "warm":         require('../design/warm.png'),
  "sunny":        require('../design/sunny.png'),
  "cloudy":       require('../design/cloudy.png'),
  "suncloudy":    require('../design/suncloudy.png'),
  "thunderstorm": require('../design/thunderstorm.png'),
}
```

This is my Component

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mood: "sunny",
    };
 }

  onMoodClick() {
    var i = 0;
    i++;
    var mood = MOOD_LIST[i];
    this.setState ({mood: mood});
  }

  getMoodImage(moodName) {
    return MOODS[moodName];
  }


   render() {
     return(
       <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress = {() => this.onMoodClick()}>
              <Image source = {this.getMoodImage(this.state.mood)} style = {[styles.center, styles.MoodTodayImage]}/>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
   }
  }
```

As of currently, when I click on the image, it only goes to the next image on the array and doesn't continue. I am also not too sure how to code what I know, such as

```
for (var i = 0; i < mood.length; i++)
```

in my React Native onMoodClick() method.

Thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always initializing the value of your variable `i` in `onMoodClick()`. Check line #1 of your method `onMoodClick()`. That's why you are always picking up the index value of 1 since on line #2 you increment the value of `i` using `i++`.

Use `states` which holds the previous value and change the value of that `state` variable when user clicks on the different mood. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Make `i` global.

```
var i = 0;

class Home extends Component {
  ....
  onMoodClick() {
    i = i === 4 ? 0 : i + 1 ;
    var mood = MOOD_LIST[i];
    this.setState ({mood: mood});
  }
  ....
}
```